# Maximal inequality of iid random variables $\{X_{ij}\}_{1\leqslant i,j \leqslant n}$

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, limit-theorems

> Suppose that $\{X_{ij}\}_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}$ are iid random variables with $\mathbb{E}(X_{11})=0$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X_{11})=1$, does the following convergence hold:
> $$
> \max_{1\leqslant  j\leqslant n}\biggl\{\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{1\leqslant i\neq i'\leqslant n}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})\biggr\} \to 0 \qquad \text{almost surely}?
> $$

Comment: I first posted this question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545745/maximal-inequality-of-iid-random-variables-x-ij-1-leqslant-i-j-leqslant), someone suggested me to post it on mathoverflow since it is an open problem.

---

### Background

I am reading the AoP paper "*Limit of the smallest eigenvalue of a large dimensional sample covariance matrix*" by Z. Bai and Y. Yin (1993). Their Lemma 2 states a generalization of the well-known Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund strong law of large numbers to the case of multiple arrays of iid random variables.

> **[Lemma 2 in [Bai and Yin (1993)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-21/issue-3/Limit-of-the-Smallest-Eigenvalue-of-a-Large-Dimensional-Sample/10.1214/aop/1176989118.full)]** Let $\{\xi_{ij},i,j=1,2,\ldots\}$ be a double array of iid random variables and let $\alpha>1/2,\beta\geqslant 0$ and $M$>0 be constants. Then as $n\to\infty$,
> $$
> \max_{j\leqslant Mn^{\beta}} \biggl|n^{-\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n (\xi_{ij}-c)\biggr|\to0\quad \text{almost surely},
> $$
> if and only if
> $$
> (i)\quad \mathbb{E}|\xi_{11}|^{(1+\beta)/\alpha}<\infty
> $$
> $$
> (ii)\quad c =  \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       \mathbb{E} \,\xi_{11},& \text{if }\alpha\leqslant 1, \\
>       \text{any number}, &\text{if }\alpha>1.
> \end{array} 
> \right.  
> $$

By our assumptions and taking $\alpha=\beta=M=1$, $\xi_i=X_{ij}^2$ in this lemma, we have
$$
\max_{j\leqslant n}\biggl|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i,j}X_{ij}^2-1\biggr|\to0\quad \text{almost surely}.
$$
This result is for square terms. I wonder if there is a similar result for the **cross terms**
$$
\max_{1\leqslant  j\leqslant n}\biggl\{\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})\biggr\} \to 0 \qquad \text{almost surely}?
$$

---

### Attempt

I can prove that $(1/n^2)\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})\to 0\; a.s.$ for any fixed $j$. But I do not know how to deal with the problem with "$\max$".

For fixed $j$,
$$
\mathrm{Var}\Bigl(\sum_{i\neq i'}X_{ij}X_{i'j}\Bigr)=2\sum_{i\neq i'}\mathrm{E}\bigl(X_{ij}^2\bigr)\cdot\mathrm{E}\bigl(X_{i'j}^2\bigr)=2(n^2-n),
$$
then by Chebyshev's inequality, for any $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
\Pr\biggl(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})>\varepsilon\biggr) =O\Bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr),
$$
which is summable. Hence, by using the Borel-Cantelli lemma, we have
$$
\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})\to 0\qquad
 \text{almost surely}.$$

If we consider $\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}$, and use the trivial inequality to bound it, we have
$$
\Pr\biggl(\max_{1\leqslant  j\leqslant n}\biggl\{\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})\biggr\}> \varepsilon\biggr)
\leqslant n\cdot \Pr\biggl(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{i1}X_{i'1})>\varepsilon\biggr)=O\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\Bigr),$$
which means
$$
\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant n}\biggl\{\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i\neq i'}(X_{ij}X_{i'j})\biggr\}\to 0\qquad
 \text{in probability}.\tag{*}
$$

How can we improve the result (*) to "almost surely"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Math Stack Exchange post, I gave a proof based on Lemma 2 in Bai and Yin (1993). I will give an alternative proof.

Expressing $\sum_{1\leqslant i\neq i'\leqslant n}X_{i,j}X_{i',j}$ as
$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,j}\right)^2-\sum_{i=1}^nX_{i,j}^2$ and considering dyadic numbers, we are reduced to show that
$$
\tag{1}\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant 2^n}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\max_{1\leqslant \ell\leqslant 2^n}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^\ell X_{i,j}\right\rvert\to 0\mbox{ almost surely}
$$
$$
\tag{2}\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant 2^n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}  \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} X_{i,j}^2\to 0\mbox{ almost surely}.
$$
By the Borel-Cantelli lemma, in order to prove (1), it suffices to show that
$$
\tag{1'}\forall\varepsilon>0, \sum_{n\geqslant 1}\mathbb P\left(\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant 2^n}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\max_{1\leqslant \ell\leqslant 2^n}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^\ell X_{i,j}\right\rvert>\varepsilon\right)  <\infty$$

which reduces, by a union bound, to prove that
$$
\tag{1''}\forall\varepsilon>0, \sum_{n\geqslant 1}2^n\mathbb P\left( \frac{1}{2^{n}}\max_{1\leqslant \ell\leqslant 2^n}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^\ell X_{i,0}\right\rvert>\varepsilon\right)  <\infty$$

Let us prove (1''). Using Corollary 1.5 in [1](https://www.esaim-ps.org/articles/ps/pdf/2019/01/ps180007.pdf) (applied with $r'=r=2$ and $B=\mathbb R$, hence $C_{r',B}=1$, we know that for each $q>0$, there exist  constants $A(q)$ and $B(q)$ such that for each $x>0$ and each independent sequence  $(Y_i)$,
$$
\mathbb P\left(\max_{1\leqslant \ell\leqslant N}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^\ell Y_i\right\rvert >x\right)\leqslant A(q)\int_0^1u^{q-1}\mathbb P\left(\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant N}\lvert Y_i\rvert>xB(q)u\right)du+A(q)x^{-q}\left(\mathbb E\left[Y_i^2\right]\right)^{q/2}.
$$

Applying this inequality to $Y_i=X_{i,0}$, $x=2^n\varepsilon$ and $q=3$ shows that
$$
 \sum_{n\geqslant 1}2^n\mathbb P\left( \frac{1}{2^{n}}\max_{1\leqslant \ell\leqslant 2^n}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^\ell X_{i,0}\right\rvert>\varepsilon\right)\leqslant  A(3)\sum_{n\geqslant 1}2^{2n}\int_0^1u^{2}\mathbb P\left( \lvert X_{i,0}\rvert>\varepsilon B(3)2^nu\right)du + A(3)\sum_{n\geqslant 1}2^{n}2^{-3n/2}\varepsilon^{-3/2}
$$
and finiteness of the first series follows from the elementary fact that $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}2^{2n}\mathbb P\left(Y>2^n\right)\leqslant 4\mathbb E\left[Y^2\right]$.

(2'') follows from an application of the similar argument as the usual strong law of large number, but the truncation level changes. Let
$Y_{i,j}=X_{i,j}^2$ and for a fixed $\varepsilon$ and $n$, let
$$
Z_{n,i,j}=Y_{i,j}\mathbf{1} \{Y_{i,j}\leqslant\varepsilon 2^{2n} \}-\mathbb E\left[Y_{i,j}\mathbf{1}\{Y_{i,j}\leqslant\varepsilon 2^{2n}\}\right],
$$
$$
W_{n,i,j}=Y_{i,j}\mathbf{1}\{Y_{i,j}>\varepsilon 2^{2n}\}-\mathbb E\left[Y_{i,j}\mathbf{1}\{Y_{i,j}>\varepsilon 2^{2n}\}\right],
$$
We thus have to show that
$$
\tag{2'}\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant 2^n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}  \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} Z_{n,i,j}\to 0\mbox{ almost surely}.
$$
$$
\tag{2''}\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant 2^n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}  \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} Z_{n,i,j}\to 0\mbox{ almost surely}.
$$
For (2'), it suffices to show (by the Borel-Cantelli lemma) that
$\sum_m\mathbb E\left[\left(\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant 2^n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}  \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} Z_{n,i,j}\right)^2\right]<\infty$.
For (2''), note that $$ \left(\{\max_{1\leqslant j\leqslant 2^n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}  \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} Z_{n,i,j}\neq 0 \}\right)\subset\bigcup_{i,j=1}^{2^n}\left(\{Y_{i,j}>\varepsilon 2^{2n}\}\right).$$

---

[1](https://www.esaim-ps.org/articles/ps/pdf/2019/01/ps180007.pdf) Deviation inequalities for Banach space valued martingales differences sequences and random fields Davide  Giraudo ESAIM: PS 23 922-946 (2019)